# How can I use Javascript to get the value of an element that was populated by a POST request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm building an HTML page that receives data from another page with the below code

```
$arrayPosition = $_POST['arrayPosition'];
echo '<span id = "arrayPosition">'.$arrayPosition.'</span>';
```

I'm then trying to use javascript to get the value of the element and pass it to a function with the below code

```
var initialPosition = document.getElementById('arrayPosition').value;

function displayWork(position){
$("#displayArtwork").detach()
                    .append(holdImages[position])
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn("fast");
}
```

When I alert the value of initial position to the screen it informs me that null is its value, however, when I inspect the element it looks like this

```
<span id="arrayPosition">4</span>
```

Am I making some really stupid error, or misunderstanding the way to access this posted data?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `span`-element has no value. Only `form`-elements can contain the `value`-attribute. To get the text inside your `span` you can use the `innerHTML`-porperty:

```
var initialPosition = document.getElementById('arrayPosition').innerHTML;
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/upk4Lc21/)

As you are already using jQuery you can also use it's `text()`-function:

```
var initialPosition = $('#arrayPosition').text();
```

here you can also use:

```
$(document.getElementById('arrayPosition')).text();
```

Harder to maintain and more difficult to read but faster than the jQuery-Selector. (see [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-performance-comparison/22))

[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/upk4Lc21/1/)

**Reference**

[.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

[.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you. I guess I'm just so used to working with form I forgot something really basic lol. I've marked your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Since `arrayPosition` is a `span`, it has no `value`. You can get its `innerHTML`:

```
var initialPosition = document.getElementById('arrayPosition').innerHTML;
```

Or using jQuery:

```
var initialPosition = $('#arrayPosition').text();
```

Comment: Hey Soroush, thanks for your answer. You are also correct, but I marked empiric's answer as correct because he included a demo. I did upvote your comment though.